# What is the probability of having at least one common ball in the two draws?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a bag which contains 100 balls numbered from 1 to 100.

Firstly, I draw 14 balls, note the number of each one and put it back in the bag. Then, I repeat the same operation.

What is the probability of having at least one common ball in the two draws?

If I am right, it is equivalent to compute the "inverse" probability of having no ball in common.

As simple as it sounds I am stuck, could anyone help me and describe the calculation in details?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate the inverse and simply subtract that from 1.

Comment: It is not called "inverse", it's called the "complement". The complement of the event that there is at least one common ball, is the event that there is no common ball between the sets of draws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it is much easier to compute the *complement* probability, the probability that the balls in the first set of draws are different from the balls in the second set of draws.

---

*First method of seeing answer:*

Ignore for the moment that the balls have numbers.  The fourteen balls we draw in the first time, we will paint red and will return to the bag in preparation for the second time we draw.

During the second drawing, what is the probability that the first ball is *not* red?  (*There are $86$ black balls and $14$ red balls*)  The probability that the first ball is black will be $\frac{86}{100}$.

We draw the second ball.  *Given that the first ball was black*, what is the probability that the second ball is also black? (*There are now $85$ black balls and $14$ red balls*)  The probability will be $\frac{85}{99}$

Continuing in this fashion and applying multiplication principle, we have the probability that there is no overlap as being $\frac{86^{\underline{14}}}{100^{\underline{14}}} = \frac{86\cdot 85\cdots 73}{100\cdot 99\cdots 87}$

---

Second method of seeing the answer:

Whatever the first balls' numbers happened to be, there will be $86$ balls which haven't yet been picked.  The number of sets of fourteen balls, none of which have previously been picked, is $\binom{86}{14}$.  The total number of ways of picking fourteen balls regardless is $\binom{100}{14}$.  As every selection of fourteen balls is equally likely, the probability is the given as the number of favorable outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes regardless.

I.e. $\binom{86}{14}/\binom{100}{14}$.  Through algebraic manipulation and simplifications, you should see that this equals the same answer as before.

---

Now, the probability that at least one ball matches will be one minus the probability found above.

Answer (score 3):

As you've noted the easiest way is to find the probability of the event not happening. The first 14 balls don't matter, so let's just color $14$ balls green. What's the probability of not picking a green ball? It's:

$$\frac{86}{100} \times \frac{85}{99} \times ... \times \frac{73}{87}$$

Now subtract this number from $1$ and you should find the probability for your problem.