# What is the probability of having no mutual ball in several draws?

Tags: probability

This question is related to [this previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846118/what-is-the-probability-of-having-at-least-one-common-ball-in-the-two-draws).

Suppose we have 100 balls numbered from 1 to 100 in a bag.

Let's say I will make $n$ random draws with replacement of $x$ balls and let's note $\mathcal{S}_i$ the $x$ values of the $i^{\text{th}}$ draw.

At each draw, I only consider the balls I have already seen, i.e. $S_{i+1} = S_{i+1} \cap S_i$ (except for $S_1$).

My question is: given a fixed value for $x$ (let's say 14), how can I bound $n$ to have $\mathcal{S}_n = \emptyset$ with a high probability?

The answers for my previous question show that for two draws, the probability that $\mathcal{S}_2 = \emptyset$ (with $x= 14$) is $\frac{86}{100} \times \frac{85}{99} \times ... \times \frac{73}{87} \approx 0.10$. For which values of $n$ could I reach something like $\mathcal{S}_n > 0.95$?

Comment: the_candyman (in an answer now deleted) is right -- the probability for $i=2$ is about $10\%$, not $46\%$ (but the expression on the left-hand side is correct, you must have miscalculated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can calculate the exact probability using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Denote the number of balls by $m$, so in your case $m=100$. The probability that $k$ particular balls haven't been drawn yet after $n-1$ draws is

$$
\left(\frac{\binom{m-k}x}{\binom mx}\right)^{n-1}\;.
$$

Thus by inclusion-exclusion the probability $p$ that all $x$ balls drawn in the $n$-th draw had already been drawn in the previous $n-1$ draws is

$$
p=\sum_{k=0}^x(-1)^k\binom xk\left(\frac{\binom{m-k}x}{\binom mx}\right)^{n-1}\;.
$$

Second, since you want high probability to have already drawn all $x$ balls drawn, it will be unlikely that there's more than one undrawn ball, so we should get a good estimate for the complement of the desired probability from the expected number of undrawn balls:

\begin{align}
p&\approx1-x\left(\frac{\binom{m-1}x}{\binom mx}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=1-x\left(1-\frac xm\right)^{n-1}\;,
\end{align}

which is just the first term of the inclusion-exclusion sum. Solving for $n$ yields

$$
n\approx\frac{\log\frac{1-p}x}{\log\left(1-\frac xm\right)}+1\;.
$$

In your example, with $m=100$, $x=14$ and $p=0.95$, this yields

\begin{align}
n&\approx\frac{\log\frac{0.05}{14}}{\log\left(1-\frac{14}{100}\right)}+1\\&\approx38.36\;,
\end{align}

and plugging the next higher integer $n=39$ into the exact expression for the probability yields

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{14}(-1)^k\binom{14}k\left(\frac{\binom{100-k}{14}}{\binom{100}{14}}\right)^{39-1}\approx95.5\%
$$

as desired.